# Installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and now computer always boots to GRUB prompt

Tags: grub2

I've done many Ubuntu installs over the years but Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has fouled up the boot process (it may be relevant that I was playing around with BIOS boot order before the installation).

I have followed recommendations in other threads on Ask Ubuntu. I Used:

```
ls (hd0,gpt5)/
```

to find that there is a `(hd0,gpt5)/boot/` and a `(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub` directory there. I then typed:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt5)  
grub> linux /boot/vminuz-5.4.0-48-generic  
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic  
grub> boot
```

I'm pretty sure I have the path right, because using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key while typing `linux /boot/vmlinuz` does the autocomplete correctly. When I tell GRUB to `boot`, a zillion lines fly by and it stops and says `no root device specified`.

If I do the following sequence, it boots Ubuntu OK:

```
grub> set root(hd0,gpt5)
grub> set prefix(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub
grub> insmod linux
grub> insmod normal
grub> normal
```

I then open a terminal and do `sudo update-grub` which seems to work, but the next time I boot, I'm back at the GRUB prompt.

It also boots correctly if I just type `exit`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Dumb mistake.  I experimented with the bios to change boot order.  The choices it lists are kind of confusing.  The same device appears multiple times.  Anyway, I played around selecting different sources for the primary boot device and eventually got it to load normally.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me twice after a clean install over an existing instalation.  What I find is the new installation creates extra a partitions were it installes the boot files so now grub cant find them.  My soution is to during the installation select other and then deleat all the current partitions on the hard drive I am installing on. Then let it create fresh patitions were it wants.